# Possible solutions of $a^b+b^a=17$

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, number-systems

Find all the possible solutions of $a^b+b^a=17$ where $a, b$ are natural numbers.

I get $a$ can't be equal to $b$ as if they are then they won't be natural numbers.

Without loss of generality, we can say that $b \gt a$.

How should I proceed. I am not able to find such numbers but how should I do it?

Should I write $a^b=17-b^a$ and analyse all the possibilities?

Or should I apply log both sides?

I can't proceed with anything.

Please help.

Comment: Since you only have natural numbers, the number of cases to check is very small.

Comment: $(1,16)$ is a pair I could immediately come up with. It shouldn't be hard to create an exhaustive list of such pairs.

Comment: One more is 3,2

Comment: I think only those two pairs

Comment: Problems asking for solutions to equations in natural numbers are often called *Diophantine*.

Comment: @hardmath but i think diophantine also includes negative integers and zero?

Comment: @vidyarthi:  That's a fair point, that the term Diophantine does not exclude by itself solutions with zero or negative integers, but often Diophantine problems will explicitly exclude them (possibly as trivial, such as in Fermat's Last Theorem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I mean, just check every possible pair, the number of cases is not very big. The possible pairs are $(16,1)$ and $(2,3)$, you see that by hand. If you take $a$ equal to 1,2 or 3 you get these 2, and for $a$ greater than 4 you get no solutions except for the case $a=16$ which is already covered

Comment: So 4 solutions?

Comment: Yes, just swap those two and there you go