# Possible values of $n$ such that $n!$ ends with $30$ zeroes

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, number-systems

If $n!$ ends with $30$ zeroes, how many values of $n$ are possible?

I know that $10$ will occur when pairs of $2$ and $5$ will occur and since $2$ occurs more times than $5$ does in $n!$, the number of trailing zeroes will be the highest power of $5$.

So I need to find those $n$ for which $n!$ will have $5$ occur $30$ times in its prime factorization.

I can't understand how should I proceed.

I know it has been asked before but I couldn't understand.

Please help.

Comment: Between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783215/possible-solutions-of-abba-17), it looks like you are just dumping your homework here for us to do for you.  Please edit to show some effort on the problem.

Comment: @lulu..I am sorry..I completely overlooked the previous question..and honestly it isn't a homework question..I read the solution available and  I couldn't understand anything beyond this..hence was expecting an explanation

Comment: Since you don't link to the other question, the most anyone is going to do here is to produce the same sort of answer (if anyone answers at all).  There's really only one way to approach a problem like this, and I'm sure the solution you have seen does it the standard way.  If you have a specific question about the other solution, ask that.

Comment: We've got a problem. 124! ends with 28 zeros, while 125! ends with 31 zeros... It looks like there is no number n such that n! ends exactly with 30 zeros

Comment: See [de Polignac's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Legendre's%20formula%20gives,formula%2C%20after%20Alphonse%20de%20Polignac.) for the standard way to get the order to which a prime divides a factorial.  Try computing with that to see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many zeros at the end of $0!$?

At the end of $5!$?

Of $10!$?

Of $15!$?

Of $20!$?

Of $25!$?

Go that far and try to understand the pattern, and then extend it to reaching 30 zeros.

Comment: There is no number having exactly 30 endng zeros. 124! has 28 and 125! has 31

Comment: @Raffaele That's fine, but I think OP should be trying to discover that.